# Publish to Azure not picking up renamed App_Code razor helper

Tags: azure

I have a site on Azure that has been using a cshtml razor helper class sitting in the App_Code folder.  It's been working fine up till now.

I changed the name of the file and published again via VS2010 publish process, and now Azure is still looking at the old file.  What do I do?

Comment: Are you sure your deployment succeeded? I've had "false positives" on the success of a publish via the Management Portal more than once - it's been VERY annoying (and wastes a lot of time)!

Comment: I published again now and no indication of any problems. It's caching the old cshtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Cloud Services or Websites? If you're using Websites, you'll need to ensure that you restart the site after publishing (restart button in the footer on the dashboard page for the website) to ensure that Azure picks up the changes. There's probably a similar mechanism for Cloud Services but I haven't used them for a long time so I can't be sure.

Comment: I tried restart, but no luck.  It's opening up a copy of the old cshtml file.

Comment: Have you verified that the new version has been deployed? You can grab it via FTP

Comment: The problem is the using statements in the cshtml are out of date as the classes they use also got renamed.  So the DLL has been replaced, but the cshtml that comes up in the custom error page is definitely out of date.  This is using Websites.

Comment: Hmm. If you FTP in, there should be a deployments directory with a bunch of guid folders inside - it might be worth checking the latest one of those to see whether the issue is with the file that was pushed to Azure with the deployment or the file that was copied across to the site itself during the deployment. Are the files in those 2 locations the same or different?

Comment: As an alternative to VS publish, have you considered using Git and Bitbucket to manage the deployment? It doesn't fix your issue, but I've found it to be pretty smooth on the whole. http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/continuous-deployment-with-windows-azure-websites-and-bitbucket/

Comment: I opened up the site via FTP and deleted the file.  Both versions of the file were present.